# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de una lista hacia un modal utilizando java .jsp-Servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Buenas tardes, estoy realizando mantenimientos de empleados en mi proyecto, de momento puedo crear , eliminar y listar todos los empleados de mi Base de Datos , pero para editarlos estoy usando un modal que coja los valores del empleado que se quiera editar,para luego realizar la operación correspondiente en el Servlet.

Estoy trabajando en netbeans-java, y con MySql Front. Adjunto capturas de mi proyecto:

[image: Lista de empleados]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen tengo un modal pero quiero pasar los parámetros del empleado al modal para luego realizar la modificación.

Comment: Me imagino que tendrías que hacerlo utilizando AJAX. Con Javascript realizaruna petición a un Servlet, y los datos recibidos asignarlos a cada campo del modal. Lo estas haciendo así o tienes otra idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: si pensaba hacerlo por jstl , pero el problema es que mi botón editar al darle click me manda al modal, pero yo quiero que mande al modal y al mismo tiempo envíe un parámetro, tienes alguna idea?

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo básico utilizando ajax: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rKq-xNHCI7nE21754GNm7b9fYigzu626. Me comentas como te fué.

Comment: hola Bryan bueno creo que ya lo tengo pero lo hice con JSTL, pero ahora viene mi otro inconveniente, por ejemplo yo quiero pasar el valor de mi tabla unidad_codigo (que hace referencia a un local en especifico) mi pagina actualizarEmple.jsp pero en un combo box.Bueno abrire otra pregunta con este nuevo caso.Igual muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: estoy tratando de realizar algo similar no se si me podria ayudar

Comment: Qeria ver el ejemplo basico de ajaxa pero el archivo esta dañado no se si me podrian ayudar